# Syncing Label fontsize with layout in PyQt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4

What is the concrete way to change the font size of a label to match the layout size its contained in through signal/slots?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below is a solution, for a `QLabel`, derived from the solution posted here: https://forum.qt.io/topic/36088/automatically-scale-text-in-qlabels/5.

This consists in a reimplementation of the `resizeEvent` method where the font size of the `QLabel` is updated according to the size of its `contentRect`. Note that the `sizePolicy` of the Qlabel has to be set to `Ignored` for this to work properly.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui     

class myQLabel(QtGui.QLabel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kargs):
        super(myQLabel, self).__init__(*args, **kargs)

        self.setSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Ignored,
                                             QtGui.QSizePolicy.Ignored))  

        self.setMinSize(14)

    def setMinSize(self, minfs):        

        f = self.font()
        f.setPixelSize(minfs)
        br = QtGui.QFontMetrics(f).boundingRect(self.text())

        self.setMinimumSize(br.width(), br.height())

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super(myQLabel, self).resizeEvent(event)

        if not self.text():
            return

        #--- fetch current parameters ----

        f = self.font()
        cr = self.contentsRect()

        #--- find the font size that fits the contentsRect ---

        fs = 1                    
        while True:

            f.setPixelSize(fs)
            br =  QtGui.QFontMetrics(f).boundingRect(self.text())

            if br.height() <= cr.height() and br.width() <= cr.width():
                fs += 1
            else:
                f.setPixelSize(max(fs - 1, 1)) # backtrack
                break  

        #--- update font size ---

        self.setFont(f)     


class myApplication(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(myApplication, self).__init__(parent)

        #---- Prepare a Layout ----

        grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()  

        for i in range(3):
            grid.addWidget(myQLabel('some text'), i, 0)  
            grid.setRowStretch(i, i+1)
            grid.setRowMinimumHeight(i, 25)

        self.setLayout(grid)
        self.resize(500, 300)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    instance = myApplication()  
    instance.show()    

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Which results in:

[image]

**Update - Optimization of resizeEvent :**

Below is an optimized version of the `resizeEvent` method that should yield better performances. It drastically reduces the number of iteration required to find the optimal value of the font size. I haven't tested it extensively though.

```
def resizeEvent(self, event):
    super(myQLabel, self).resizeEvent(event)        

    if not self.text():
        return

    #--- fetch current parameters ----

    f = self.font()
    cr = self.contentsRect()

    #--- iterate to find the font size that fits the contentsRect ---

    dw = event.size().width() - event.oldSize().width()   # width change
    dh = event.size().height() - event.oldSize().height() # height change

    fs = max(f.pixelSize(), 1)        
    while True:

        f.setPixelSize(fs)
        br =  QtGui.QFontMetrics(f).boundingRect(self.text())

        if dw >= 0 and dh >= 0: # label is expanding

            if br.height() <= cr.height() and br.width() <= cr.width():
                fs += 1
            else:
                f.setPixelSize(max(fs - 1, 1)) # backtrack
                break                    

        else: # label is shrinking

            if br.height() > cr.height() or br.width() > cr.width():
                fs -= 1
            else:
                break

        if fs < 1: break

    #--- update font size ---           

    self.setFont(f)
```

Comment: How can I give an initial size to labels? is it possible after ignoring size policy?

Comment: @Amen Well, the initial size of the label will be mostly determined on the layout side of your application. But I can see that it could be useful to set a minimum size on the label, so it is not collapsed by the stretching of the other elements of the UI. See the updated example.