# Pyqt label changes window size when resizing label

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am learning pyqt and am trying to make a piece of text in the middle of the widget that changes font size when the widget size is changed based on the size of the widget window. I have something that works how I want except for the fact that when expanding the window horizontally, at a certain point, it automatically expands the window vertically as well.

I suspect it is related to padding. The desired behavior when dragging the window size horizontally is for the text to scale in size until it would cause the window to change in vertical dimension, and at that point, not change the font size anymore.

Below is what I have so far with a bunch of print statements to figure out sizes but for some reason, nothing matched the size of the window.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget,QHBoxLayout,QLabel,QApplication,QSizePolicy)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont, QFontMetrics
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt,pyqtSignal
import sys

class alarm(QWidget):
    resized = pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 150, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle("Alarm Clock")

        self.init_UI()

    def init_UI(self):
        self.counter = 0
        self.resized.connect(self.set_font_size)
        self.time = QLabel('Test')
        self.time.setFont(QFont('Times New Roman'))
        self.time.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding,QSizePolicy.Expanding)

        self.time.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(self.time)

        self.setLayout(hbox)
    def resizeEvent(self,event):
        self.resized.emit()

    def set_font_size(self):
        curr_geo = self.geometry().width()
        font = self.time.font()
        curr_pixel_size = font.pixelSize()
        new_pixel_size = curr_geo/3

        font.setPixelSize(new_pixel_size)
        t = self.time.contentsRect().height()
        print('Label contents rect: ',t)
        print('label height: ' + str(t))
        new_bounding = QFontMetrics(font).boundingRect(self.time.text())

        print('New bounding: ' + str(new_bounding.height()))
        print('Total height: ' + str(self.geometry().height()))
        if new_bounding.height() > self.geometry().height():
            font.setPixelSize(curr_pixel_size)
            self.time.setFont(font)
        else:
            font.setPixelSize(new_pixel_size)
            self.time.setFont(font)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    alarm = alarm()
    alarm.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

Use height of label `time`

```
if new_bounding.height() > self.time.height():
```

Or even without `else:`

```
    if new_bounding.height() <= self.time.height():
        font.setPixelSize(new_pixel_size)
        self.time.setFont(font)
```

---

Full code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget,QHBoxLayout,QLabel,QApplication,QSizePolicy)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont, QFontMetrics
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt,pyqtSignal
import sys

class alarm(QWidget):
    resized = pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 150, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle("Alarm Clock")

        self.init_UI()

    def init_UI(self):
        self.counter = 0
        self.resized.connect(self.set_font_size)
        self.time = QLabel('Test')
        self.time.setFont(QFont('Times New Roman'))
        self.time.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding,QSizePolicy.Expanding)

        self.time.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(self.time)

        self.setLayout(hbox)
    def resizeEvent(self,event):
        self.resized.emit()

    def set_font_size(self):
        curr_geo = self.geometry().width()
        font = self.time.font()
        curr_pixel_size = font.pixelSize()
        new_pixel_size = curr_geo/3

        font.setPixelSize(new_pixel_size)
        t = self.time.contentsRect().height()
        print('Label contents rect: ',t)
        print('label height: ' + str(t))
        new_bounding = QFontMetrics(font).boundingRect(self.time.text())

        print('New bounding: ' + str(new_bounding.height()))
        print('Geometry height: ' + str(self.geometry().height()))
        print('Label height: ' + str(self.time.height()))
        if new_bounding.height() <= self.time.height():
            font.setPixelSize(new_pixel_size)
            self.time.setFont(font)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    alarm = alarm()
    alarm.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood - the problem was that it was automatically resizing the height of the entire window when I was only adjusting the width of it as it was scaling the text. I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29852498/syncing-label-fontsize-with-layout-in-pyqt)

Comment: when I change widow's width then it doesn't change window's height. Did you expect something more ?

Comment: I added full code.

Comment: I checked you link and it seems it works similar to my code. It compares text's height with label's height.